# Udp Socket handling

Tags: delphi, udp, delphi-7

I want to use UDP Socket to simply send an audio stream. My problem is that i can't get it working i thought it would be simpler then using TCP IP.

What i did i droped a UDPSocket component on my form and for the server part i used this code

```
  with udpServer do
  begin
    LocalHost := '127.0.0.1';
    LocalPort := '5002';
    Open();
    Active := True;
  end;
```

For the client application this :

```
   with udpClient do
      begin
        RemoteHost := '192.0.168.100'; //my local address
        RemotePort := '5002';
        Open();
        Active := True;
      end;
```

The problem is i am not receving anything. What i am doing wrong i don't have any third-party software that can block the connection.

I didn't find any suitable example for using this component any source of inspiration will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: btw i am using Delphi 7 for this task

Comment: Is there a reason you're opting for UDP other than it feels simpler? TCP is definitely a better solution than UDP for the broadcast unless you have a very specific need for it. As far as sockets go the Indy components are very easy to use and there are a lot of good examples.

Comment: @DanielChapman UDP is faster and is recommended for voice streaming because it doesn't request lost packets to be resent...

Comment: that makes sense. I'd definitely recommend the Indy UDP server if you're using Delphi7. I don't have the IDE on this computer but it has a tutorial when you install the components. It is very straightforward. For testing on a single machine bind the server to an address like 127.0.0.1:9098 and then bind your client to 127.0.0.1:9099, Generally by specifying the ports you can get around the double bind problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the server and the client connect on the same IP.

Usually if you set the server application IP address to 0.0.0.0 it will bind to any available IP address on the given port, including 127.0.0.1.

Then the client must connect to one of the bound IPs. Instead, you had the server listening on 127.0.0.1 and the client connect to 192.0.168.100.

Don't be fooled by the "LocalHost" property name. "Local" here just mean you have to set a "local" IP, an IP assigned to the local machine, not a "remote" (of another machine) one, while the client of course will connect to a "remote" IP, that of the server.

127.0.0.1 is a good choice if and only if you want your server to be available only to local application, because that IP scope is limited to the same machine. If you want to make it available outside the machine, you have to bind it to a valid IP.

Whatever issue you have, tools like [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org) or [Microsoft Network Monitor](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=4865) are very useful to understand what's going on.

Comment: I made the modifications to fit what you have answered unfortunatley it doesn't work i tried testing even on 2 machines .... +1 for the effort thanks.

Comment: "Doesn't work" is a very generic issue :) You've to explain better what happens. For example the tools I suggested will show you what actually happens at the network level, but issues could be at your application level also. Does the connection happens properly? Are the packet sent? Are the packet received? And so on...

Answer (score 1):

You are binding the server to `127.0.0.1`, so it will only accept clients that connect to `127.0.0.1` specifically. Your client is connecting to `192.0.168.100` (perhaps you meant `192.168.0.100`?) instead.

You need to bind the server to the IP(s) that clients are actually connecting to, or else bind it to `0.0.0.0` to accept connections on any local IP.

Even though UDP is connectionless, this same rule applies to both UDP and TCP, as it applies to the lower level IP routing layer that they both share.

Comment: Thanks for your reply , the same things was suggested by ldsandon but unfortunately it doesn't work. i still don't receive anything...

Comment: You have not shown any of your reading or writing code, so everyone has to guess as to the problem.. Please show the rest of your UDP code.